# Using (+) in jpql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I am migrating sql query to JPQL query and facing an issue. My SQL query has (+) in below condition:

```
and SP.REQUIRED_PART_ID =pr.part_seq_id(+)
```

I am new to JPQL and does not know how to convert (+) to JPQL. Can someone please guide me how to do it?

Comment: Isn't a `right outer join`?. That you can don in JPQL.

Comment: You should stop using the deprecated outer join syntax in Oracle and use a proper `LEFT JOIN` operator.

Comment: Yes certainly, but this query was not written by me. It was written very long time ago by some other person. I have task of migrating it to JPQL in hand.

Comment: Add the mappings of the two enityes.